# Stackexchange site on Reverse Engineering

Tags: discussion

I didn't know where to post this question - maybe in metastackoverflow - but I thought that people interesed in security may also be interested in reverse engineering.

How about a separate stackexchange site for reverse engineering (not only malware or for exploits but all kinds of reverse code engineering (maybe even hardware reverse engineering but i guess not many people are doing that since it's more expensive etc.)

Comment: [reverseengineering.se] is up and live!

Answer (score 4):

It could well be an MSO on-topic question, however I think you have the right audience here - might move it to meta.security though.

@George has given good advice - if you think there is a big enough audience the best route is to create a new Area51 proposal, however there are a couple of gotchas:

- in many countries reverse engineering is illegal (which might reduce your possible audience)
- are you going to have enough '[good questions](https://security.stackexchange.com/faq#questions)' in the reverse engineering topic to make it qualify?
- currently, if you have a well-structured reverse-engineering question it would be on topic here, so why would we need to create a new site?

Comment: In which countries is reverse engineering illegal? Does it depend on license agreement?

Comment: It depends a lot on patents, licenses and other contracts. Have a read of http://lwn.net/Articles/134642/ http://www.pirateparty.org.uk/forum/viewtopic.php?f=11&t=2413 and http://forums.contractoruk.com/accounting-legal/62272-reverse-engineering-schema-any-ethical-legal-imlications.html

Answer (score 3):

If you wish to make a new StackExchange site for your own use so you can reverse engineer, check with [Meta Stack Overflow](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/), but don't get your hopes up.

If on the other hand, you wish to recommend that a new StackExchange be created for public use, go to [Area 51](http://area51.stackexchange.com/), [search the existing sites](http://area51.stackexchange.com/search?q=reverse+engineering), and you will find that you were [not the only person who wants this](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/26607/reverse-engineering).

Answer (score 0):

The art and process of reverse engineering is legal (in most places) even if reverse engineering a multitude of covered products isn't. Questions like https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4798356/amd64-nopw-assembly-instruction can use their own home. I'd say go for it. I'd sign on as a committer to an Area 51 proposal.

Comment: I don't see why that question is a poor fit on SO. It could almost fly on Sec.SE too. [What's the point of creating a separate site?](http://discuss.area51.stackexchange.com/questions/9549/what-would-a-reverse-engineering-site-offer-that-existing-sites-dont)