# IT Security Legal Jurisdiction

Tags: discussion, acceptable-question, acceptable-answer

Under what legal jurisdiction(s) does IT Security operate, and what are the compliance issues?

This is mainly a response to [Stackexchange site on Reverse Engineering](https://security.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/655/stackexchange-site-on-reverse-engineering) but it caused me to think about other potential legal issues.

For example. If posting specific vulnerability information for software X is against the law in country Y, does IT security have any legal compliance issues?

Answer (score 2):

As far as I'm aware, everything for StackExchange operates from New York, NY, USA. Other than my best guess, that's a question that their legal rep would need to chime in on.

Answer (score 1):

Very interesting question - I'd be tempted to say that you'd end up with joint liability in many cases so the individual who posted, **and** SE may be liable for legal infractions.

but I am not a lawyer - I am interested in any input from those who are...

Answer (score 0):

I feel that a legal.SE site might be needed some time in the future, that would be kind of handy anyways =p

However, I did do some reading.. this would be great in concept, but there is a difference between a novice programmer giving you some bad advice that just messes up a program, and a novice "lawyer" giving you "legal advice" that lands you in jail